# Why does my mac keep crashing under panic report?

Tags: macos, crash, kernel-panic

does anyone understand what this error code could suggest?

```
Anonymous UUID:      --------------------------------
Wed Dec 17 13:03:49 2014
*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff801d41e80a): Kernel trap at 0xffffff7f9da63db4, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x0000000000000000, CR3: 0x00000000205d3000, CR4: 0x00000000001626e0
RAX: 0x0000000000000011, RBX: 0x0000000000000000, RCX: 0xffffff81284db4f0, RDX: 0x0000000000000011
RSP: 0xffffff81284db420, RBP: 0xffffff81284db440, RSI: 0xffffff803290c008, RDI: 0x0000000000000000
R8:  0xffffff802f0d0b08, R9:  0x00000000000088ee, R10: 0x0000000000000003, R11: 0x0000000000000002
R12: 0xffffff803290c008, R13: 0xffffff7f9dab0b98, R14: 0xffffff81284db4f0, R15: 0xffffff7f9dab0b80
RFL: 0x0000000000010202, RIP: 0xffffff7f9da63db4, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0x0000000000000000, Error code: 0x0000000000000002, Fault CPU: 0x0

Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff81284db0d0 : 0xffffff801d33a811 
0xffffff81284db150 : 0xffffff801d41e80a 
0xffffff81284db310 : 0xffffff801d43a443 
0xffffff81284db330 : 0xffffff7f9da63db4 
0xffffff81284db440 : 0xffffff7f9da62023 
0xffffff81284db4b0 : 0xffffff7f9da6031f 
0xffffff81284db530 : 0xffffff7f9da5b8fe 
0xffffff81284db5c0 : 0xffffff7f9da4201b 
0xffffff81284db5f0 : 0xffffff801d67731b 
0xffffff81284db970 : 0xffffff801d674487 
0xffffff81284dbb40 : 0xffffff801d672459 
0xffffff81284dbd10 : 0xffffff801d65d1c1 
0xffffff81284dbd30 : 0xffffff801d5d68a2 
0xffffff81284dbd60 : 0xffffff801d5b1ec4 
0xffffff81284dbdf0 : 0xffffff801d5ad87e 
0xffffff81284dbeb0 : 0xffffff801d5b0364 
0xffffff81284dbfb0 : 0xffffff801d4192c7 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.symantec.kext.internetSecurity(5.4f4)[77BF0BC5-BEF4-34FF-9160-C22D470BB3B2]@0xffffff7f9da39000->0xffffff7f9da47fff
         com.symantec.kext.ips(3.9.2f1)[70330C8B-669A-35A8-A7DD-9E428BE89B9F]@0xffffff7f9da58000->0xffffff7f9dab0fff
            dependency: com.symantec.kext.internetSecurity(5.4f4)[77BF0BC5-BEF4-34FF-9160-C22D470BB3B2]@0xffffff7f9da39000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
14B25

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 14.0.0: Fri Sep 19 00:26:44 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2782.1.97~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 89E10306-BC78-3A3B-955C-7C4922577E61
Kernel slide:     0x000000001d000000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff801d200000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff801d100000
System model name: iMac14,3 (Mac-77EB7D7DAF985301)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 35080293823668
last loaded kext at 276550473617: com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs 1.10 (addr 0xffffff7f9fe4e000, size 69632)
last unloaded kext at 337057038683: com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs   1.10 (addr 0xffffff7f9fe4e000, size 61440)
loaded kexts:
com.symantec.kext.SymAPComm 12.7.1f4
com.symantec.kext.fw    5.3.1f4
com.symantec.kext.filesecurity  12.7f4
com.symantec.kext.ips   3.9.2f1
com.symantec.kext.pf    5.7.1f4
com.symantec.kext.internetSecurity  5.4f4
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch   85.3
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.3.1f2
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.14.37
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.1.0d1
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   267.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   267.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 2.0.2
com.apple.GeForce   10.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.3
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.4d1
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.3.1f2
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.10
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD5000Graphics   10.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferAzul  10.0.0
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 35
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    705.4.1
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.6.5
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.6.5
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.1.2b3
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   901.19.10
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.0.7
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXHCI   705.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   161
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard  175.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   175.5
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   4.3.1f2
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  260.30
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 267.0
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.15
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   200.6
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAGK100Hal    10.0.0
com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman  10.0.0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.8.0d49
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink    4.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.3.1f2
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.3.1f2
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 267.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 267.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.13d1
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   97
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.7.21
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    156.4
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  705.4.9
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    3.1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 4.2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   700.52
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.7.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 705.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 389.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
Unable to gather system configuration information.Model: iMac14,3, BootROM IM143.0118.B07, 4 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.9 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.17f7
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M, PCIe, 1024 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343531533641465238412D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343531533641465238412D50422020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x111), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.15.124.12.10)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.1f2 15015, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: APPLE HDD HTS541010A9E662, 1 TB
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
Thunderbolt Bus: iMac, Apple Inc., 23.10
```

Answer (score 2):

The bits that matter here:

```
Extensions in backtrace:
com.symantec.kext.internetSecurity(5.4f4)[77BF0BC5-BEF4-34FF-9160-C22D470BB3B2]@0xffffff7f9da39000->0xffffff7f9da47fff
com.symantec.kext.ips(3.9.2f1)[70330C8B-669A-35A8-A7DD-9E428BE89B9F]@0xffffff7f9da58000->0xffffff7f9dab0fff
dependency:
com.symantec.kext.internetSecurity(5.4f4)[77BF0BC5-BEF4-34FF-9160-C22D470BB3B2]@0xffffff7f9da39000
```

Uninstall (or update if available) Symantec Internet Security. Its kernel extensions are causing the panics.

Comment: as @Alex said..uninstall Symantec or get a updated version (if they have it)